Spring boot kafka 3.2.2 - handle exceptions
I should develop a java application that reads messages from a topic with a single partition. I have only one consumer. I'm not authorized as a producer, so I can't write to a failure queue. I will probably have to use tables to manage failures and also the order of messages. I can't miss a single message. The listener will be under transaction @Transactional("transactionManager").  I started reading the documentation a few days ago, but I'm not clear on how to handle exceptions well to avoid losing messages.
Unfortunately I don't have much time available before releasing a first version, can you please provide me with some example code that handles exceptions without losing messages?

See if this doc can help somehow: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/annotation-error-handling.html
